# Is there any downside to using height: 0px; overflow: hidden; instead of display: none?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any downside to using height: 0px; overflow: hidden; instead of display: none?

Comment: Yes, that's two properties you have to change instead of one.

Comment: Is there an upside it? (not being snarky... am intrigued as to why you'd want to do it that way, when you know the 'right' way)

Comment: I assume you mean `height: 0px; width: 0px`?

Comment: @colinmarc - What the OP has in the title is correct, `height: 0px; width: 0px;` wouldn't do anything to hide children without the `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I meant `height: 0px; width: 0px; overflow: hidden`. What the OP has might still take up horizontal space, as mdma points out below.

Comment: Explanation: I did it as a temporary fix for jWYISWYG (rich text editor).  There's a bug in jWYSIWYG where if you set it to display: none; then to display: block; it comes out with a funny width.

I'm trying to fix it, but in the meantime I figured this would be a quick fix.

Comment: @Walker - If you use `.show()` and `.hide()`, it'll store the previous `display` value and restore it, not necessarily `block` :)

Comment: @Nick - I tried it, unfortunately I got the same behavior.  I did a few basic trimmings on the base jWYSIWYG editor which may have caused the problem.  I'm going to debug and see if I can figure out the problem!

Comment: @Nick - I actually thing that may be the problem after a little debugging... I have a three step posting process (check out devel.jobzle.com - it has the height 0px hack on it).  In step 2 I have a text box with my box around it... if I start on that slide then hide the page it works fine... but if it starts as display: none - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `display` CSS property is built into a lot more methods, e.g. [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for starters (among many others, for example you can't just call [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) anymore to show the element).  Aside from that, most browsers optimize `display: none` better, if any parent has `display: none;` it need not render the element, so it can speed up things quite a bit ignoring these elements.

More important than all of the jQuery parts: stepping back a minute from both a CSS *and* JavaScript standpoint, why not use the property provided *explicitly for this purpose*? :)

Comment: One reason is what is mentioned in the OP...you can't get the dimensions of a child element of something set to display: none, but you can if the parent is set to height: 0px. It's the only situation where I can see using this option.

Answer (score 2):

I think logically it is cleaner to use `display:none` since that correctly describes the intent. Using a 0-height object with clipping (overflow:hidden) will not be visible, but may still take up space in the page, since it has width. It may also be more expensive to render, depending upon the browser, since the browser may attempt to render the element and then clip to an empty rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the former If you need to give focus to or register input from a hidden input, such as a `textarea`. Other than that, you should use the `display: none` descriptor for its intended purpose.